# why npm checked for so many dependencies for single package

Tags: node.js

I was running `npm install` to install only 1 package called `generator-angular`

```
npm install --global generator-angular
```

you have no idea how many dependencies this npm have checked, it is still rolling I will just pick a few

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-angular
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/generator-angular
....
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/diff
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
```

are these really dependencies ? like `diff` `ansi`? or am I making some mistakes ?

Comment: did you end up with an error?

Comment: @pka2012 not yet, it's just slow and last for hours. some of the sources are extremely slow here within GFW.

Comment: That's just the modularity of packages on npm and is fairly common. In fact it's arguably better that way to have a package to "one" thing and "one" thing well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are all real dependencies.  `generator-angular` is a particularly heavy module.

One thing to note is that many of them are "peer dependencies".  This means that they are installed next to, rather than inside, `generator-angular`.  This allows them to be shared by your application as well as other modules with peer dependencies.  So in addition to `generator-angular`, you are getting access to `generator-karma`, `grunt-cli`, `bower`, and `yo`.

If you are depending on any of these already, make sure you are installing all of your modules in the same place so they don't get installed multiple times.

Comment: @zinking Like I said, make sure they're installed in the same place.  Did you install yo and bower globally as well?